# How to extract the predicted classes when using the return_sequence and TimeDistributed parameters in an LSTM model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am using this LSTM model to classify my data into two classes:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=120, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, train_target, batch_size=64, epochs=1000, validation_split=0.2)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, test_target)
```

My data shape is `[168 (samples), 402 (timesteps), 1000 (features)]`. Train set `[134 (samples), 402 (timesteps), 1000 (features)]`) and Test set `[34 (samples), 402 (timesteps), 1000 (features)]`).
I am using `return_sequences=True` and `TimeDistributed` to obtain the classification decision of each timestep.

`model.predict_classes(X_test)` gives a decision matrix of `(34(samples), 402 (timesteps))` which corresponds to the decision of each timestep.

How, in addition to the decision for each timestep I can have the global decision for each of the 34 samples with this same model?

```
model.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_24 (LSTM)               (None, 402, 120)          538080    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_24 (TimeDis (None, 402, 1)            121       
=================================================================
Total params: 538,201
Trainable params: 538,201
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `model.summary()` to the question? Using it, we can analyse the input/output shapes of the layers in the `model`.

Comment: "he 200 samples are divided into 2 classes : 160 (train) and 40 (test)" - you mean data is split into 2 parts? What is the number of classes? 1? are you trying to do a binary classification?

Comment: I have corrected the number of samples. I make a binary classification, dense(1) because I amdoing a one-to-one prediction

Comment: I am a bit confused. Can you elaborate on `How can I find the global classification decision of each of the 34 test samples?` .. what do you mean global classification decision? what is the expected output shape?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal : I can't find a way to get the classification decision for each sample (e.g. sample 1 correctly classified... sample 34 misclassified)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to map `(34, 402, 1000) -> (34, 1)`, instead of `(34, 402, 1000) -> (34, 402, 1)` which you are getting with time distributing the output `Dense` layer.

You can use an additional `LSTM` with `return_sequences=False` and a standard `Dense` layer (without time distributed layer) to do this mapping during training. Then `model.predict` should get you what you need.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

inp = layers.Input((402,1000))
x = layers.LSTM(120, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(inp)
x = layers.LSTM(120, activation='tanh')(x)
out = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)


model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)        [(None, 402, 1000)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_10 (LSTM)               (None, 402, 120)          538080    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_11 (LSTM)               (None, 120)               115680    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 121       
=================================================================
Total params: 653,881
Trainable params: 653,881
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I want to have the global and each step decision from the same model. Using two models is the only solution ?

Comment: Do you have the time step-level decisions as well as global decisions to train on? you will need a `X_train (168, 402,1000)`, a `y_train1 (168, 402, 1)` and a `y_train2 (168, 1)`